# Simple limit facts about coordinate functions $\pi^i$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Example 1.** Let $x\mapsto \pi^i(x)$ be the mapping $\pi^i: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ assigning to each $x=(x^1,\dots,x^m)$ in
> $\mathbb{R}^m$ its $i$th coordinate $x^i$. Thus $\pi^i(x)=x^i.$ If
> $a=(a^1,\dots,a^m)$, then obviously $$\pi^i(x)\to a^i\quad
>  \mathrm{as}\ x\to a.$$ The functon $x\mapsto \pi^i(x)$ does not tend
> to any finite value nor to infinity as $x\to \infty$ if $m>1$.
>
> On the other hand, $f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m}(\pi^i(x))^2\to \infty$
> as $x\to \infty.$

The only fact which is bothering me is the second paragraph "The functon $x\mapsto \pi^i(x)$ does not tend to any finite value not to infinity as $x\to \infty$ if $m>1$." It does not look correct to me. Am I wrong? If yes, then please explain this is true.

Thanks a lor for your attention!

Comment: Well, the second "not" looks like it should be "nor".

Comment: First, say what $x \to\infty$ means, where $x \in \mathbb R^m$.

Comment: It is saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\pi^i(x)$ doesn't exist (in $[-\infty,\infty]$) in any reasonable sense, and I think it means to say "nor to infinity".

Comment: To amplify what GEdgar said, can you find what your text says it means for a function to have some finite limit $L$ as $x$ tends to infinity. Then, maybe think about points that are far from the origin but near one of the axes.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, corrected! thanks!

Comment: @peek-a-boo, can you explain why is this true? How to prove that?

Comment: First of all, can you write down a definition for "$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$" (assume $f:\Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}$ is a given function)? Once you can do this, you can negate this definition and show why $\pi^i$ satisfies the negation.

Comment: @peek-a-boo,Let's put it in a different way: I am wondering the fact that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\pi^i(x)$ doesn't exists, does it follow from Cauchy criterion for convergence of function?

Comment: sure; and you can even consider the sequence of points $\xi_n=(-1)^nne_i$, where $e_i=(0,\dots, 1,\dots, 0)$ is the vector with $1$ in the $i^{th}$ place. But to properly show that this proves the non-existence of a limit, you first need precise definitions. Are you able to write the definitions down?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$, then $(\exists \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} f(x))\Leftrightarrow  (\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \mathrm{ball}\ B(0;\delta): \sup \{|f(x')-f(x'')|: x',x''\in \mathbb{R}^m \setminus B(0;\delta) \} <\epsilon)$.
Taking negation we obtain: $(\nexists \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} f(x))\Leftrightarrow  (\exists \epsilon>0 \ \forall \mathrm{ball}\ B(0;\delta): \sup \{|f(x')-f(x'')|: x',x''\in \mathbb{R}^m \setminus B(0;\delta) \} \geq\epsilon)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, In our case we have function $\pi_1:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$. If we take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, then for any ball centered at $0$ of radius $\delta>0$ we can take points $x'=(\delta,0,\dots,0), x''=(\delta+1,0,\dots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus B(0;\delta)$ and hence $|\pi_1(x')-\pi_1(x'')|=1>\epsilon.$ Does it make sense?

Comment: right. That takes care of limits existing in $\Bbb{R}$. THe case where the limit does/does not exist in $[-\infty,\infty]$ can be handled similarly.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, $(\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty)\Leftrightarrow  (\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \mathrm{ball}\ B(0;\delta): \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus B(0;\delta) \Rightarrow |\pi_1(x)|>\epsilon)$.
Taking negation we obtain: $(\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)\neq \infty)\Leftrightarrow  (\exists \epsilon>0 \ \forall \mathrm{ball}\ B(0;\delta): \exists x'\in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus B(0;\delta): |\pi_1(x')|\leq\epsilon)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, In our case we have function $\pi_1:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$. If we take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, then for any ball centered at $0$ of radius $\delta>0$ we can take the point $x'=(1/4,\delta,0,\dots,0)\in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus B(0;\delta)$ and hence $|\pi_1(x')|=1/4\leq \epsilon.$